# HTML body width: fitting page, but with maximum value

Tags: html, width

How do I make a webpage fit to the size of the browser width, while I still have
a maximum width (say, e.g., width="1000px") for the body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What below code will do is that till the body width gets to 1000px it will take the full width of browser after exceeding 1000px  it stop increasing body width

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, "max-width" did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set content to match the size of a browser viewport by using `vw` and `vh` properties ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)).

If you're saying you want the body to have `max-width` of 1000px but be scrollable if `vw < 1000`, it should probably be placed within a child element of some kind:

HTML:

`<body class="viewport">
  <div class="my_element"></div>
</body>`

CSS:

`.viewport {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}`

`.my_element {
  max-width: 1000px;
}`

Comment: Thanks, especially max-width was useful.